# How can I get the timezone offset without the DST formatted correctly?

Tags: java, timezone, java-time, timezone-offset

I have not found a way to get the timezone offset without  Daylight Savings Time interference.

```
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();
...
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(s);
ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(zone);
ZoneOffset offset = zdt.getOffset();
```

This would seem like it works, but the initial DataTime might be influenced by DST.

There is also this:

```
int rawOffset = tZone.getRawOffset();
```

However, this is always a positive number, so we don't ever get `-05:00` back.

So what I want is a way to get the offset without DST interference. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. A zone doesn't have a fixed offset. The offset depends on the date.

Comment: As a sidenote: `getRawOffset()` is close to what you want and should definitely return negative values where appropriate. The difference is that you might not get historically correct (or even relevant) values from that.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It sounds like you're trying to re-calculate something yourself which should probably be handled by some `java.time` class instead. What do you need that information for?

Comment: If I understood correclty, you want to know what's the timezone's offset when it's not DST, right? And it must be independent of what the current date is?

Comment: You are exaclty correct,  @Hugo.

Comment: There is **no such thing** as a “timezone's offset when it's not DST” “independent of what the current date”. A time zone by definition is a historical collection of the past, present, * future changes to offset-from-UTC used by a particular region. So there is no such thing as a ‘normal offset’, no baseline offset, which is what you seem to seek. Your question may stem from a common fundamental misunderstanding about time zones: They are not real, not in the sense of being natural. Zones & offsets are created by humans, specifically by capricious politicians who frequently change the rules.

Comment: Couldn't you consider DST as a modification of the base timezone?  I can find no record of a timezone changing since established in America.  However, DST changes all the time.  You say there is 'no such thing as a 'normal offset', but there is.  What else would you call "ZoneRules.getStandardOffset(Instant)" (the answer below)?

Comment: @markthegrea The modification of the base (non-DST) timezone is not common, but it also happens, specially before 1900, when every city had its own local time and then decided to change to some UTC offset. The thing is: it can happen [at any time, anywhere](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/maine-ast.html) - because it depends on governments and laws, not on "logical" reasons. But I understand your point of view, it's such an uncommon event that we don't even consider it (but we should).

Comment: @markthegrea `ZoneRules.getStandardOffset(Instant)` gets what is the standard offset **at a specific given moment** (as the standard can change over time, you always need an `Instant` as reference) - just because it's one today, it doesn't mean it was always the same in past. It also doesn't mean that it will always be the same in the future: if tomorrow some government decides to change the timezone of a country/state/region/whatever, we'll all have to update our systems with this new rule (and `getStandardOffset` for `Instant`'s in the future will then return this new offset).

Comment: Just complementing: in Brazil, the state of Acre had a standard offset of -05 without DST. From 1986 to 1988 they started having DST (standard -05, DST -04), from 1989 to 2008, just standard -05 without DST, then from 2009 to 2013 the standard changed to -04 (without DST), and since 2014 the standard is back to -05 (without DST). And it's not the only case - you can find more [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time). And there's always a government somewhere wanting to change the standard offset. So, even to get the standard offset, you need an `Instant` as a reference.

Comment: So does the JVM need to be updated to get this info?  I mean, obviously it does, but i have never heard of this as an update!  Must be in the regular versioning.  Great discussion!

Comment: There's a tool to update it: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html - and also a list of most recent updates: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html

Comment: The tzupdater tool can be used if you can't (or don't want to) update your java version, but of course the new updates to timezone info are included in newer JVM versions as well. For example, in **Java SE 8u131 b32**, the [updated tzdata2017b was included](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/documentation/8u131-revision-builds-relnotes-3682515.html#8u131-b32)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ZoneRules.getStandardOffset(Instant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getStandardOffset-java.time.Instant-).

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(s);
ZoneRules rules = zone.getRules();
ZoneOffset standardOffset = rules.getStandardOffset(Instant.now());
```

Comment: But you are using "Instant.now()" which is influenced by Dayllight Savings time.

Comment: `Instant.now()` represents the current time with no knowledge of "DST" or "timezones", so it can't be DST tainted (except if your local clock is wrong because of timezone shenanigans, then all bets are off anyway).

Comment: So I played around with this and it seems to be what I want.  However, can you explain why Instant.now() is even needed?  Why is any date need to find the offset of a timezone from UTC?  Why should the date matter?

Comment: The instant can be used if you want  “historic information on how the standard offset has changed over time”, to quote [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getStandardOffset-java.time.Instant-). Many times in history has a country or area changed its standard offset. I believe that when I was a child, Spain was in a different zone from mine, but nowadays it is in the same zone.

Comment: This answer contains my favourite code snippet among the answers. It does not contain my favourite explanation. We could use more of the latter, please…

Answer (score 0):

TimeZone.getRawOffset() will return the correct historical offset, according to the Java API Documentation.

> public abstract int getRawOffset()
>
> Returns the amount of time in milliseconds to add to UTC to get standard time in this time zone. Because this value is not affected by daylight saving time, it is called raw offset.
>
> If an underlying TimeZone implementation subclass supports historical GMT offset changes, the method returns the raw offset value of the current date. In Honolulu, for example, its raw offset changed from GMT-10:30 to GMT-10:00 in 1947, and this method always returns -36000000 milliseconds (i.e., -10 hours).
>
> Returns:
>      the amount of raw offset time in milliseconds to add to UTC.
>   See Also:
>      Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET

from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getRawOffset()

Comment: Do we *need* to use the otherwise outdated class `TimeZone`? Is there a solution with the modern classes?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep in mind that **offsets change over time** (even the standard ones), basically because of governments, laws and other external factors.

That's why the API requires an `Instant` as a reference: to know what was the standard offset at that specific moment (no matter if the `Instant` is in the past, present or future). You can't say what the offset is without knowing when in time you are. And that's why [@Joachim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44397937/7605325) is the correct one.

But as you told in the comments that you don't want to depend on `Instant.now()`, I've done the code below - and keep in mind that the solution is not 100% ideal, because of the reasons above. It's just the best I've got following your criteria.

---

You can do that using the `java.time.zone.ZoneRules` class, that you can get directly from your `ZoneId` instance:

```
// pick a timezone with DST
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo");
// get rules
ZoneRules rules = zone.getRules();
// check if offset changes over time (if it returns false, it means is not fixed, so it has DST)
System.out.println(rules.isFixedOffset()); // false
```

In the code above, `rules.isFixedOffset()` returns `false`, which means that the corresponding timezone's offset changes over time (so, it has DST changes).

To know when those DST changes occur, you must get all the transitions:

```
// get all transitions (all dates where DST starts or ends)
List<ZoneOffsetTransition> transitions = rules.getTransitions();
transitions.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

This prints lots of lines (as this timezone has DST almost every year). Here's a sample of the last 2 lines:

> Transition[Overlap at 2039-02-20T00:00-02:00 to -03:00
>   Transition[Gap at 2039-10-16T00:00-03:00 to -02:00]

This means that in **2039-02-20** at midnight, the offset will change from `-02:00` to `-03:00` (DST ends - clocks move back 1 hour), and in **2039-10-16** at midnight the offset will change from `-03:00` to `-02:00` (DST starts - clocks move forward 1 hour).

So, if you want to know the offset when it's not DST, you just get the last transition, check if it's a gap or overlap and get the offset after or before:

```
// get the last transition
ZoneOffsetTransition last = transitions.get(transitions.size() - 1);

// find the offset without DST interference
ZoneOffset offsetWithoutDST;

// overlap means that clock moves back 1 hour (when DST ends) 
if(last.isOverlap()) {
    // DST ends, get the offset after it
    offsetWithoutDST = last.getOffsetAfter();
} else {
    // DST starts, get the offset before it
    offsetWithoutDST = last.getOffsetBefore();
}
System.out.println(offsetWithoutDST);
```

In this case, it prints `-03:00`, which is the "normal" offset for `America/Sao_Paulo` timezone (when it's not DST).

---

**PS:** please note that DST and even standard offsets can vary a lot over time.

Just because the offset is one today, it doesn't mean it was always the same: governments can change the offset at any time, and in very past dates - like before 1900 - the offsets were much more messy than today (every city had its own time, with offsets like `-03:06:28` and so on).

The code above gets the standard (non-DST) offset **for the current timezone's rules**. If you want to know what was the non-DST offset 30 years ago, you can use [@Joachim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44397937/7605325) (passing an `Instant` of 30 years ago as a parameter).

Comment: You’ve researched thoroughly! Nice. What are the advantage/s of your approach over the two other answers? And if for a zone I cannot find a transition in 1987 — well, I suppose it just means I can pick any instant within that year and query its offset, do you agree?

Comment: Also, can we be sure that a transition is always a transition to or from DST? At least there must also be a transition when the standard offset changes due to some changed legislation?

Comment: This is great information!  I am blown away that the JVM has all of these transitions in it.  I believe Joachim Sauer answer is much easier, however.  Thanks for the education!

Comment: @OleV.V. The OP told that didn't want to depend on `Instant.now()`, and to get the current standard offset, the last-transition-approach is the best I could get. I'm aware this is not a perfect solution because offsets change over time and the ideal is to always have a date/time reference. So, this solution is the best possible to get the **current** standard offset without depending on `Instant.now()`, but to get an offset in the past, of course you need a date/time reference, and I admit my solution is not ideal.

Comment: And according to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneOffsetTransition.html): "A transition between two offsets is **normally** the result of a daylight savings cutover". So it's not 100% guaranteed, but after UTC took place, we can assume that most of the time they are DST related. And when it's not, I wonder how the API decides what's the "standard".

Comment: @markthegrea Please keep in mind that this solution is not ideal (I've updated the answer explaining that), it's just the best I've got without having to depend on `Instant.now()` (as you've told in the comments). But Joachim's answer is the correct one, because you must always have an `Instant` as reference to know what the offset is. And I must also admit that I finished this code just for the challenge...